# Randomisation for 2 site clinical study

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation

If I want to conduct a randomised study in 2 sites comparing two clinical treatment arms, and every site is expected to include 60-80 patients, is it acceptable to randomise every new patient with simple coin toss (one centralised scheme for all patients, regardless of site) or is some stratified randomisation more appropriate (stratified per center)? I have tried to understand urn randomisation and wonder if it would be a better model. If so, can you suggest an easy way of doing so? I have found RANDI3 online (http://dschrimpf.github.com/randi3/) but I have no idea whether I can 'trust' its output. Any advice welcome

Answer (score 1):

Stratification is used to balance treatments within important subgroups. By "important" I mean related to the primary outcome. Trial site (centre) is often thought to be important because patients at different centres are likely to differ in severity of illness or socio-economic background, and so may well have different average risks of poor outcome. However, you should consider whether this is likely to be the case in your trial before automatically stratifying by centre.

The most [popular method](http://www.trialsjournal.com/content/13/1/198) of balancing treatments within strata is [random permuted blocks](https://www.sealedenvelope.com/randomisation/protocols/). This is easy to understand and you can [create stratified blocked lists](https://www.sealedenvelope.com/simple-randomiser/v1/lists) yourself so you don't need to trust a "black box" like RANDI3.